Dockerfile COPY doesn't alter line endings to Linux
I have a Windows C# project locally. I have a .editorconfig that gives errors for inconsistent line endings (everything should be CRLF).
I check out the code using git, and the line endings are CRLF as per the Windows convention.
I then create a Docker image, via a Dockerfile that uses COPY to copy the source from Windows into a Docker image, and builds.   Out of around 300 source files, 3 files are identified as having an incorrect line ending.   If I manually set those files (on Windows) to have LF line endings, then Docker build is happy, but then it doesn't build on Windows/Visual Studio (IDE0055).
Bear in mind, I am NOT checking out code on the Docker build, it is copying already checked out code.   Also, why only 3 files out of hundreds?  I could understand if all the source files were errors, but they aren't.  These 3 files are not in a folder on their own (there are 20 other source files in the same folder).
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Why would you expect the COPY statement to fix line endings? Theres nothing in the documentation that suggests that it does that.
